# Sphinx Group By for both RT index and plain index

Tags: sphinx

I need to put Group by for Both Rt index and plain index...

For example:
  I have 4 records with different document ids in plain index with persons of same age..

And also I have 2 records of the same document ids with same age in RT index...

When i'm putting GROUP BY by combining two Index...Grouping count  want to remain same for the same document ids that are in the both index... But for me returning  Grouping count which are included with the entire count for same document ids too...

```
     Rt index data: 

     +-----------+------+        
     | id        | age  |
     +-----------+------+
     |         1 |   47 |
     |    123455 |   47 |
     |    123456 |  127 |
     |    123457 |   55 |
     | 101100063 |   51 |

     Plain index..

     +-----------+------+
     | id        | age  |
     +-----------+------+
     | 123455    |   47 |
     | 101100061 |   47 |
     | 111123456 |  127 |
     | 156123457 |   55 |
     | 101100063 |   51 |


    After Grouping Age when combing both i need the result as, need the count by skipping same document ids  


    +-----------+------+----------|
    | id        | age  | Count    |
    +-----------+------+----------|
    | 123455    |   47 | 3        |
    | 101100061 |  127 | 2        |
    | 111123456 |   55 | 1        |
    | 156123457 |   51 | 1        |
```

Comment: please include table schema and desired output

Comment: I had posted my table schema that what exactly i need from the sphinx...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` rather than just `COUNT(*)` to get the count. (assuming you using sphinxQL of course!)

Comment: You could try using setGroupDistinct, but dont think it will work on the id in the API.

Comment: As I thought. Try SphinxQL